# Permission Required for deleteAfterRead on Camel S3 Component

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel

I'm using the Camel S3 component to read objects uploaded to a particular S3 bucket. The objects are read successfully.

However, using "*deleteAfterRead=true*"  fails with a 403 (no permission)

I have granted all the permissions in the "write" category, on the bucket, but I still get the error.

Right now these are the permissions. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-camel-bucket"
        },

        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It may be helpful to mention the version you are using 2.x or 3.x, and preferably a stack trace.

Comment: This is with Camel v3.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: for the `s3:DeleteObject` Action, I needed to specify the resource with a `*` at the end. So, `arn:aws:s3:::my-camel-bucket/*` instead of simply `arn:aws:s3:::my-camel-bucket`

However, for the ListBucket, I needed just the bucket name. So, what I have working now is this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-camel-bucket"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-camel-bucket/*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
    }
  ]
}
```